# Who can i do specific time settings on periodic calendar in controlm v8+

Tags: control-m

I want to make a complexe scheduling using a **single job** that have one periodic calendar depending on specific date.

for example the job must be executed this way:

- 1st day of the mounth two time in 01:00AM and 01:00PM
- second day of the mounth every hour
- between the 05 an 28 of each mounth every 2 hours

can this be maked with period Calendar or Rule Based Calendar?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using a **single job**.

Calendars are used to control when a job is scheduled (ordered on), nothing more.
[image: Calendar Definition]

In order to achieve what you want i'd suggest setting up three identical jobs and simply modify the execution settings of each to suit one of the three criteria.

Comment: Thank you that's what I ended up doing